# Sending a POST request using httplib

Tags: python, post, http-post, httplib

I'm trying to send data using `httplib`. Here is my code:

```
headers = {'User-agent': 'agent','Accept': 'application/json'}
params = { 'api_key':'kjdksnjd45555','ts':455555555}
data = {'job1':42,'job2':85}
params['data'] = json.dumps(data,separators =(',',':'))
re = requests.post(url,headers,params)
print re.json()
```

When I using requests, it work very nice, but not when I use `httplib`

```
params = urllib.urlencode(params)
con = httplib.HTTPConnection('api.sandbox.gengo.com')
con.request("POST", "/api/v", param, headers)
r2 = con.getresponse()
r2.read()
```

It returns the following error :

```
"msg":"\\"api_key\\" is a required field"}
```

(This means that it can not recover my data.)

What can I try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo on line:

```
con.request("POST", "/api/v", param, headers)
```

Shouldn't that be `params` and not `param`. This would explain why the server is responding about the missing `api_key`

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of HTTPConnection.request is not the http request parameters.
It is the POST request body. The parameters are part of the url and should be sent as such.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html?#http.client.HTTPConnection

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two mistakes. First you are using `param` instead of `params` in your third line, but also you are passing the parameters as request body not as request parameters.

Try next code:

```py
params = urllib.urlencode(params)
con = httplib.HTTPConnection('api.sandbox.gengo.com')
con.request("POST", "/api/v?" + params, "", headers)
r2 = con.getresponse()
r2.read()
```